# How to stop all "play" commands currently running in other shells?

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, killall, sox

I have a script that invokes the play command when I press f10. I would like to edit that script so if I press it while an audio file is `play`ing, then it kills that first before playing the next file.

What command am I looking for? Something like,

`killall play` ?

Comment: `killall play` sounds good. Have you tried it?

Comment: @ByteCommander lol nope!

Comment: @ByteCommander That literally works. you might as well toss the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Ok, there it is :)

Comment: Not exactly most elegant solution, I'd say.  The script can kill itself , if it's literally named "play". Can you provide more details here ? how is the script actually named ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as you already intuitively thought, `killall play` is the way to go.

What it does is to terminate all running processes with the name "play" by sending them the signal SIGTERM.

You can read more about it in its manpage by typing `man killall` or visiting it [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/killall).